# Python urllib.urlopen() call doesn't work with a URL that a browser accepts

Tags: python, urllib, bitbucket

If I point Firefox at http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/Home/ReleaseNotes, I get a page of HTML. But if I try this in Python:

```
import urllib

site = 'http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/Home/ReleaseNotes'
req = urllib.urlopen(site)
text = req.read()
```

I get the following:

500 Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use the firefox addon `Tamper data` to see what the browser is really doing. Maybe you're missing something.

Comment: It works for me.  Perhaps a temporary problem with bitbucket?

Comment: @Matthew, you sure it's working? when I run it I get no exception but the 587-bytes long HTML I get DOES say "500 Internal Server Error" just like the OP observed.

Comment: @Alex, Just tried it again and I get the 500 error.  But it did work before.  `"500" in text` returned false, and printing it filled three pages of my console.

Comment: Btw what do you want to achieve? You know that the wiki is clonable?

Comment: I was just trying to learn how urllib works. As a first exercise I thought I'd write a script to examine this page to see what the latest version of TortoiseHg was. Looks like I should have picked some other page, and left this one for the second exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, bitbucket does some user agent detection (to detect mercurial clients for example). Just [changing the user agent](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib._urlopener) fixes it (if it doesn't have `urllib` as a substring).

You should fill an issue regarding this: http://bitbucket.org/jespern/bitbucket/issues/new/

Comment: Changing the user agent fixed it, like you said. TVM.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing nothing wrong, on the surface, and as the error page says you should contact the site's administrators because they're the ones with the server logs which may explain what's happening. Fortunately, bitbucket's site admins are a friendly bunch!

No doubt there is some header or combination of headers that browsers set one way, urllib sets another way, and a bug on the server gets tickled in the latter case. You may want to see exactly what headers are being sent e.g. with firebug in firefox, and reproduce those until you isolate exactly the server bug; most likely it's going to be the user agent or some "accept"-ish header that's tickling that bug.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong -- it looks like this server was just down? Your script worked fine for me ('text' contained the same data as that displayed in the browser).

Comment: Funny, I can reproduce the OP's problem exactly: from any browser I see a rich page, from urllib a 587-bytes HTML result which DOES say `<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>` etc etc.